# Set Variable Varchar2 to date fields

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Script that I update a Date field

this is a part of my script

```
    var VARCHAR2(8 char);

var = '01/01/22';
    update table1 t set t.date = to_date(var,'dd/mm/yy');
```

and then I got a null value in field date

why I dont have a 01/01/22 value ??

### could you help me please !!

ANSWER       :::::::::::     PETIT PAPA merci :D

### I created I new Varible with Date type

and I affecte the to_date to this variable

```
date_var Date;

date_var :=to_date(var,'dd/mm/yy');

update table1 t set t.date = date_var where ...;
```

and it work THANK YOU everyONE

Comment: did you use commit?

Comment: yes and when I tried like this it work  correctly      t.date = to_date('01/01/22','dd/mm/yy');

Comment: I ve answered your question

Comment: How can this question have two upvotes?

Answer (score 0):

Try
    to_date(var,'dd/mm/yy');

Answer (score 0):

### try this:

```
var := '01/01/22';
    update table1 t set t.date = to_date(var,'dd/mm/yy');

commit;
```

Comment: this is exactly what I did

Comment: I trace the logs of the to_date(..) I got this value 01-JAN-22
it is normal ??

Comment: so try to_date(var,'dd/MON/yy')

Comment: did you try  `:= `

Answer (score 0):

I try this code to me, and work fine:

```
create table t( data date);
```

Then

```
insert into t (data) 
values (to_date('01/01/22','dd/mm/yy'));
```

Now we check data in table

```
select * from t;
```

We got expected result. That's for inserting.
For updating

```
update t set data = to_date('01/02/22','dd/mm/yy');
```

Now check

```
select * from t;
```

We got `01-FEB-22`

But beware when updating without where clause it will update all records

Answer (score -1):

Miistake here is that it's not `todate` it is `to_date`